# How to allow users to select the Android app's installation location (SD card or internal storage)

Tags: java, android

I need to allow a user to select whether the app should be installed to an SD card or the internal memory. I cannot find any information about that at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

The only thing I can do is to specify `android:installLocation` as "internalOnly", "auto", or "preferExternal". However, I'd like to let users choose that when the app is being installed.

Is it possible to do that on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **It's not possible to explicitly let user choose where to install your app**.

Before it's installed, your app can't run so you can't run any code at that time.

Options you mention: "internalOnly", "auto" and "preferExternal" are only options.

From personal experience, I recommend you to use "auto" unless you have some restrictions that force you to use "internalOnly".

"preferExternal" can produce errors on some older devices ("*can't open SD card*" or something like that, I can't remember).